# How to use pow() in fxpmath library

Tags: python, fixed-point

I'm using the `fxpmath` library but basic arithmetic doesn't seem to work. Are values getting corrupted or am I using powers that should not be computed?

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

def test_pure_q96():
    x = Fxp(1.0001, dtype="Q64.96") ** (Fxp(4055, dtype="Q64.96") / 2)

    print(x)
    print(x/2)
```

The output is:

```
1.2247538232335937
2.036149027162537e-13
```

The first value seems right, the second should only be half as much as the first?

Comment: Printing out `x.info(verbose=3)` might be informative, to see exactly how that result is being represented.  I'm not sure that `Q64.96` is a usable dtype, as it would require that the underlying storage be a 128-bit int, which numpy doesn't seem to support.

Comment: Is there another Qx.96 type that could be workable? Possibly a larger integer?

Comment: I think you're going to have limit the total bits to 64 - so `Q2.62` would be about the most precise you could get for this particular value.  (You couldn't represent the 4055 constant with that dtype, but then you don't need to.)

Comment: Super helpful, looks like I will need to find another library for Q64.96 as I need to simulate that exact behavior!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailed answer is at [issue #38](https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath/issues/38). The following is a summary:

When a fractional (`n_frac != 0`) is used as exponent in `power` function and `op_sizing='optimal'`, *fxpmath* can not resolve the amount of fractional bits for result, so it performs power calculation using `float` and store the result in a `Fxp` with *optimal* size. As the result value is 1.2247538232335937(...) a size of `fxp-s54/52 (Q2.52)` is considered optimal.

When `x/2` is calculated, the constant 2 is taken as an `Fxp` with same size (see @Suneesh Jacob comment), and 2 can't be represented with only one bit for integer part (`Q2.52`). That's the reason of value error after `x/2`.

If a *power* calculation is required to be performed in `Q64.96`, configure *fxpmath* to work with op_sizing='same', in that way the fractional part for result is known.

```py
Fxp(1.0001, dtype="Q64.96", op_sizing='same')**(Fxp(4055/2))
```

> exponent doesn't need to be `Q64.96` necessarily.

---

You can also use a template to work with same precision:

```py
Fxp.template = Fxp(dtype='Q64.96', op_sizing='same')

# since here all Fxp created without explicit size will be `Q64.96` with op_sizing='same'

z = Fxp(1.0001) # same that z = Fxp(1.0001, dtype="Q64.96", op_sizing='same')
# ...
z = Fxp(1.0001)**(Fxp(4055/2, dtype='Q16.2')) 
z.info(3)

Fxp.template = None # disable template
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath) says:

> The constant is converted into a new Fxp object before math operation, where the Fxp size for the constant operand is defined by x.config.op_input_size in examples above. The default value for op_input_size is 'best' (best enoguh precision to represent the constant value), but it could be used 'same' to force the constant's size equals to Fxp object size (x in the examples).

If you enter `x.config.op_input_size`, it prints `'same'` rather than `'best'`. So, try changing the config by entering `x.config.op_input_size='best'`.

The code looks something like this:

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

def test_pure_q96():
    x = Fxp(1.0001, dtype="Q64.96") ** (Fxp(4055, dtype="Q64.96") / 2)
    x.config.op_input_size='best'

    print(x)
    print(x/2)
```

Comment: `fxpmath` has operator overloading https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath#arithmetic.

Operator overloading allows you to use the same operators that work for built-in types with your own classes! It's great and you can learn more about operator overloading in Python here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operator-overloading.

Comment: @Peteris If you enter `x.config.op_input_size`, it prints `'same'` rather than `'best'`. So, try changing the config by entering `x.config.op_input_size='best'`, and now try `print(x/2)` and it'll print `0.6123769116167967`

Comment: Nice, this does seem more like a hack/workaround to me since this way you would have to use `x.config.op_input_size='best'` after every single operation that uses a constant. Also in documentation, the default value is meant to be "best", but here we see that the default value is "same".

Comment: See @jasonharper comment - this could very well be a hack.